# LINQ .Select() is quite slow

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, select, entity-framework-core

I'm using EF Core. I have about 2500 records in database table Articles.

In management studio with EF compiled SQL I get result in few MS. In program about 30secs. .Select() is the issue. I don't know how to optimize it anymore.

1: before

```
List<Article> articles = await db.Articles.Select(x => new Article { Title = x.Title, Description = x.Description, Body = x.Body, Authors = x.Authors, PhotoAuthors = x.PhotoAuthors, Tags = x.Tags }).ToListAsync();
```

2: now

```
List<Article> articles = await db.Articles.FromSql("SELECT [x].[Title], [x].[Description], [x].[Body], [x].[Authors], [x].[PhotoAuthors], [x].[Tags] FROM[Articles] AS[x]").Select(x => new Article { Title = x.Title, Description = x.Description, Body = x.Body, Authors = x.Authors, PhotoAuthors = x.PhotoAuthors, Tags = x.Tags }).ToListAsync();
```

Result is still same :/

**EDIT**: Solution is to not use .ToList()

Using:

```
IQueryable<Article> articles = db.Articles.Select(x => new Article { Title = x.Title, Description = x.Description, Body = x.Body, Authors = x.Authors, PhotoAuthors = x.PhotoAuthors, Tags = x.Tags }).AsNoTracking();
```

IQueryable lose functions like .Split which I used later or Intersects.

Comment: I've struggled a lot with the EF 6 (Not Ef Core) performance and I've noticed the problem was the SQL result mapping to Classes. I was working on a legacy system and can't solve the modeling mistakes to improve the performance issue... =/ Now I use Dapper and everything about performance is far better.

Comment: Why do you need select - isn't `db.Articles` returning  `IQueryable<Article>`?

Comment: Well I'm trying to select neccessary columns. Without select it also is slow.. because creating 2500 objects

Comment: What's the end result `articles` you're looking for (or how many)? e.g. Are you filtering your articles afterwards?

Comment: Yes I filter articles then. I need to use Split function to look if any keyword matches word

Comment: 2500 is not that much these days. It's hard to give you good advice based on the provided information. Eliminate select, eliminate tracking, eliminate `async` - how long it takes to execute `db.Articles.AsNoTracking().ToList()`? Turn EF Core logging on and let us see the log starting with *Executed DbCommand (Time ms) ...*

Comment: @IvanStoev I rewritten it... I'm no longer using ToList just IQueryable and that's solution. My problem was to "split" those columns by whitespace: title, body, description. I was using .Split(' ').Intersects.. so now I'm using keywords.Any(y => x.Title.IndexOf(y, .......... which works and I have results under 2 secs which is good

Comment: I'm a bit baffled, Entity Framework has you store an object, with the proper query code to generate the object.  Why would you need to `new Article` when it should return a collection of article anyways?

Comment: @Greg sure but SQL Engine works faster with less columns to select than whole table

Comment: Your question is just to vague (downvoted).  We don't know *at all* what you're trying to do *in the question itself*.  You simply state it's slow.

Comment: @user1085907 True, shorter row length is quicker.  The performance with millions of records, one being twenty columns vs a hundred columns would be around four milliseconds.  SQL should be able to grab a hundred columns with seven million rows in about a second.  Obviously those results can vary based on other criteria, the point though you're adding a conversion and thousands of additional objects to memory.  Are we positive the database query is the culprit, not the transformation of data after the query is returned.  EF settings / query generation, what does SQL Analyzer say?

Comment: This was clearly an XY problem (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 0):

I think you're over thinking it.

```
var articles = db.Articles.ToList();
```

gets you a list of articles. If you really don't want to select extra fields, then you could do a

```
var articles = db.Articles.Select(x => new {...}).ToList();
```

but generally speaking you shouldn't see much of a difference between grabbing the entirety of vs just some of the headers. What you probably need is a `.Where` to limit things, but if you really need it all, just keep it simple.

Comment: I need it all. I' am making search function

Comment: Shouldn't the searching happen in the db to avoid pulling back all data?  Think of what will happen when you get to 10,000 or 1 million articles...

Comment: What do you suggest? How would you limit search function?

Comment: 'Pagination' would be the right approach when you have a large record set.

Comment: If you're making a search function, you shouldn't be pulling back all your data, searching it in code and then performing. That's what a .Where is for. Limit your criteria in your request. There isn't much that can't be done in the request that can be be done only once you have all the data.

Comment: @Sparrow well but to create pagination I need to first search which articles are matching keywords

Comment: Yes, and as @gilliduck is saying, you should use the 'where' clause before calling 'ToList'. The 'where' staement will filter the data at SQL server level and returns the rows that you need

Answer (score 0):

`AsNoTracking()` should make it faster

```
var articles = db.Articles.AsNoTracking().ToList();
```

Comment: Tried, still not helping :/

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was due to `Cartesian explosion` in EF `Select`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/single-split-queries#cartesian-explosion

Example:

```
var blogs = ctx.Blogs
    .Select(b => new
    {
        b.Id,
        b.Name,
        b.Posts,
        b.Contributors
    })
    .ToList();
```

Changed to:

```
var blogs = ctx.Blogs
    .Select(b => new
    {
        b.Id,
        b.Name,
        b.Posts,
        b.Contributors
    })
    .AsSplitQuery().AsNoTracking().ToList();
```

Went from over 5000 ms to 70 ms.